# Can i export grails sdk from windows to ubuntu

Tags: grails, ubuntu-12.04

I have several grails versions installed on my windows machine. I want to install grails on ubuntu. Can i use the same sdk in ubuntu by creating new environment variables for ubuntu? Do i need to download all the versions again for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GVM to manage your Groovy & Grails environment! http://gvmtool.net